# PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser find() crashing while traversing past a null element

Tags: php, null, find, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to chain [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) find() to traverse through HTML, however it seems to crash when one of the children is absent. For example:

```
$obj = $page->find('#headings', 0)->find('h4', 0)->nodes[0];
```

will cause PHP to die() if find('#headings', 0) or find('h4', 0) returns null (ie. if the element is not in the HTML), but will succeed if all the elements are present.

Is there a way to make the above chain simply return null instead of crashing PHP? I've considered modifying simplehtmldom but not sure how. The find() function is listed below:

```
// find dom node by css selector
// Paperg - allow us to specify that we want case insensitive testing of the value of the selector.
function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
    return $this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
}
```

**EDIT: (Solution)**

Following user1508519's suggestion I have created an alternative nfind() function. With this approach PHP will still flag a notice if a null property (as opposed to method - the find() method returns an empty node when chained) is referenced further down the chain but will not crash without explanation as it will when using find().

```
// modified version of simple_html_dom->find() that will return an empty node instead of null when chained if an element is not found. simple_html_dom_node->nfind() must also be created for this to work.
function nfind($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
                $this->root->nfind($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
}
```

The actual code that performs the find operation can be found in simple_html_dom_node->find() and the following function should be placed inside simple_html_dom_node for the whole package to work correctly (last line only modified - for some reason wrapping the original find() function it and checking for is_null still seems to crash PHP

```
//modifed version of simple_html_dom_node->find()
function nfind($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
    $selectors = $this->parse_selector($selector);
    if (($count=count($selectors))===0) return array();
    $found_keys = array();

    // find each selector
    for ($c=0; $c<$count; ++$c)
    {
        // The change on the below line was documented on the sourceforge code tracker id 2788009
        // used to be: if (($levle=count($selectors[0]))===0) return array();
        if (($levle=count($selectors[$c]))===0) return array();
        if (!isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_BEGIN])) return array();

        $head = array($this->_[HDOM_INFO_BEGIN]=>1);

        // handle descendant selectors, no recursive!
        for ($l=0; $l<$levle; ++$l)
        {
            $ret = array();
            foreach ($head as $k=>$v)
            {
                $n = ($k===-1) ? $this->dom->root : $this->dom->nodes[$k];
                //PaperG - Pass this optional parameter on to the seek function.
                $n->seek($selectors[$c][$l], $ret, $lowercase);
            }
            $head = $ret;
        }

        foreach ($head as $k=>$v)
        {
            if (!isset($found_keys[$k]))
                $found_keys[$k] = 1;
        }
    }

    // sort keys
    ksort($found_keys);

    $found = array();
    foreach ($found_keys as $k=>$v)
        $found[] = $this->dom->nodes[$k];

    // return nth-element or array
    if (is_null($idx)) return $found;
    else if ($idx<0) $idx = count($found) + $idx;
    return (isset($found[$idx])) ? $found[$idx] : new simple_html_dom_node('');
}
```

Thanks again to user1508519 for helping me come to the desired solution while providing a range of equally valid alternatives! Comments are welcome as to the validity of the solution/potential side effects or if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this should anyone have further input.

Comment: to be expected. each stage returns an object, or nothing if there's nothing there. can't use nothing as an object... If you can't depend on the structure of that document being consistent and always available, you'll have to unchain and test each level for results before going deeper.

Comment: `die()`? Do you mean it throws an error because you're attempting to lookup a property on a `null` reference?

Comment: @alex Yes but no error is thrown - I just get a blank page from the point that the error occurs

Comment: @MarcB Yes that's the problem - I want to be able to handle the absence of an expected element in a chain without testing each find() operation individually

Comment: you can't, not with unmodified simple_html. that's why it's **SIMPLE**.

Comment: The real question is, if you're hard-coding find statements, then why would you want it do dynamically exit on null?

Comment: @user1508519 I would like to be able to handle the case where the element does not exist

Comment: @MarcB is there a way I can modify simplehtmldom to provide this functionality?

Comment: Then modify the .php file where you found the find definition to echo an error on null. It's that simple. It's not a big deal to modify it if you refuse to manually check.

Comment: @MarcB or is there another library you know of that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do it in a chain? Why not check in subsequent checks if each call is null? Like the comment said, you cannot operate on a null object. If you were doing a foreach loop, it would remove the need for a null check.

```
$obj = $page->find('#headings', 0);
if (!is_null($obj)) {
   $obj = $page->find('h4', 0);
   if (!is_null($obj))
       // ...continue...
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false)
{
    if (is_null($this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase)))
    {
         die("error");
         // throw exception?
    } else // whatever

}
```

OR

Write a wrapper function of your own that internally calls simple's find.

Like

```
function wrapper($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false) {
    // yep 
}
```

Comment: It seems much cleaner and more readable in a chain - Your answer works well and the foreach method is a good point but ideally I'd like to be able to run the chain with predictable results (or at least be able to handle the error ) if an element does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$obj = ($h4 = $page->find('#headings h4', 0)) ? $h4->nodes[0] : null;
```